# Observing a generic event, but ignoring most instances

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

Is it bad practice to listen for a common event, but then to filter out all but a tiny number of those events?

As an example, say I want to modify a particular block. I can listen for the `core_layout_block_create_after` event, filter out the particular block I'm interested in and make my changes. However, this seems really inefficient if the block I'm working with is only loaded infrequently, because its on an obscure page. The `core_layout_block_create_after` event can be fired up to 60 times on some pages, which will incur the overhead of the observer function call and my filtering logic, just for those events to be ignored.

I've been examining the core code for guidance, but cannot see any event filtering. Observers in the core code either listen for very specific events that are fired infrequently, or if they listen for a more frequently fired generic event, they take action every time its fired rather than filtering out only the version of the event they are interesting in.

Thinking about it, if you were a core developer who had written an observer that listened for a generic event and filtered out all the versions you weren't interested in, then you could just go and add a specific event to the core code which met your needs. This might explain why the core observers don't appear to filter events.

Reviewing the core code also shows that some really common generic events, such as `core_layout_block_create_after`, `core_abstract_load_after`, `catalog_category_load_after` and `core_collection_abstract_load_after` are never listened for by core code. The only reason for these events to exist is to provide places for third party code to hook into. The generic nature of these events must mean that core developers anticipated third party developers filtering out the versions of the events they were interested in.

Whilst my instinct is to use observers when possible and never override core files because of the potential for future conflicts, I'm wondering if there are occasions where overriding an obscure core block would be the better choice.